# Read the characters of an executable for file transfers in C

Tags: c, sockets, file-io

So recently for a course project, I decided to make myself a program that could transfer a file across a lan network and integrate it into the linux operating system (In this case, all I did was add it to the context menu) using a socket server.

The way it works is essentially,

```
Server is waiting.
Client connects.
Client sends a message of 1024 length with the first 4 characters reserved
The first 4 characters are used to store an int which will state the length of the message

server recieves them, writes them, then waits for the next block
when the server recieves a message where the length is 0  
it ends the transfer and closes the files
```

This works for text files flawlessly. With improvements on my last code thanks to helpful feedback, I've managed to create something where the OS actually recognizes the file extension, regardless of the type. However for things like pngs they show up black, for exe's they immediately segfault.

What can I change in my reading and writing to get this to work regardless of file type? I'm not sure where to go, as what I have should work

Additional info: I am coding in C. To open the file I use fopen, fgetc and fputc.
Here is an exert from my code for my sever:

```
          while (1){

     n = read(newsockfd,message,1024);
     if (n < 0) {
        fclose(fptr2);
        error("ERROR reading from socket");
        }
    //The first 4 bytes/characters are used to store the length.
    //I read them by getting a pointer to the first char and then reading it as
    //an int by casting it. This works with no problem
    char *p=&message;
    int *p2=(int*)p;
    int length=*p2;
     //Checks if the length is 0, if so, exit
     if (length==0)
        break;
    //writes to the file
        for (int i=4;i<length;i++){
          fputc(message[i], fptr2);
    }

     n = write(newsockfd,"Ready",5);
     if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
     bzero(message,255);
     }

     fclose(fptr2);
     //n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
     //if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
     printf("Done.\n");
     return 0; 
}
```

Exert from my client, which reads the file in and then sends it.

```
    while (finished!=0&&c!=EOF)
{

   for (int i =4;i<1024;i++)
   {
       if (c==EOF)
       {
    char* p=&message;
    int* pi=(int*)p;
    *pi=i;
    finished=0;
    //printf("length is:%d\n",i);
    break;
    }
    //printf("%c",c);
       message[i]=c;
       //fputc(c, fptr2);
       c = fgetc(fptr1);    
   }
if (finished!=0) 
{
char* p=&message;
int* pi=(int*)p;
*pi=1024;
}
   n = write(sockfd,message,1024);
   if (n < 0) 
     {
       fclose(fptr1);
       error("ERROR writing to socket");
     }
   bzero(message,1024);
   //reading
   n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
  if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR reading from socket");
}
```

Comment: Executables have lots of NUL characters in them, so you're going to need to rethink your design. Also note that `NUL` which is a zero character commonly written as `'\0'`, is not the same as `NULL`, which is a zero pointer.

Comment: EOF is a condition. It is not a character and it is not equals to NULL

Comment: Send the file size before sending the file data. Send and receive as many bytes as the file size indicates, regardless of what the file bytes actually are

Comment: When using `fopen()` set the mode to binary, `"b"`.  That will not make a difference on Linux, but if you go across platforms (esp. Windows) then it could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the most important change to get this to work is changing when the program stops reading. EOF is simply -1, in a text file, this is no problem, however in other files this value can be found  potentially anywhere. In order to read in the characters properly you must first get the file length, then simply read characters until you reach that.

```
fseek(fptr1, 0L, SEEK_END);
int sz = ftell(fptr1);
rewind(fptr1);
int count=0;
while (count!=sz)
{
//other code left out for simplicity
c = fgetc(fptr1);
count++;
}
```

With this change, my program works properly.

Answer (score 0):

0x00 is a *valid* character for a binary file, so you can't "stop" when you see one [like you can for a string].

You are using the first char of a packet as an EOF marker (i.e. non-zero means valid data and zero means EOF). But, note that the first data char in a packet could be zero, so you have to use a one byte "header" that doesn't have data chars in it, merely the "stop" flag char [if you will]:

```
while (1) {
    // Reading
    n = read(newsockfd, message, 1023);
    if (n < 0) {
        fclose(fptr2);
        error("ERROR reading from socket");
    }

    // Checks if the first character is null, if so, exit
    if (message[0] == 0)
        break;

    // writes to the file
    // NOTE: now the data starts at offset 1!
    int i = 1;
    for (;  i < n;  ++i) {
        fputc(message[i], fptr2);
    }

    i = 0;
    n = write(newsockfd, "Ready", 5);
    if (n < 0)
        error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(message, 1023);
}

fclose(fptr2);
```

But, a simpler way is to just read until the length comes back zero:

```
while (1) {
    // Reading
    n = read(newsockfd, message, 1024);

    // end of data
    if (n == 0)
        break;

    // error
    if (n < 0) {
        fclose(fptr2);
        error("ERROR reading from socket");
    }

    // writes to the file
    fwrite(message,1,n,fptr2);

    i = 0;
    n = write(newsockfd, "Ready", 5);
    if (n < 0)
        error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(message, 1023);
}

fclose(fptr2);
```